# Beaufiulsoup: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' and is not subscriptable

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup and I'm getting the error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'" and also "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

I know my code works when I use it to search for a single restaurant. However when I try to make a loop for all restaurants, then I get an error.

Here is my screen recording showing the problem. https://streamable.com/pok13

The rest of the code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/wsv1kfNm

```
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
restaurant_address = yelp_containers[yelp_container].find("address", {
  "class": 'lemon--address__373c0__2sPac'
}).get_text()
print("restaurant_address: ", restaurant_address)




# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
restaurant_starCount = yelp_containers[yelp_container].find("div", {
  "class": "lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__30xVZ i-stars--regular-4__373c0__2R5IO border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I"
})['aria-label']
print("restaurant_starCount: ", restaurant_starCount)



# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
restaurant_district = yelp_containers[yelp_container].find("div", {
  "class": "lemon--div__373c0__1mboc display--inline-block__373c0__25zhW border-color--default__373c0__2xHhl"
}).text
print("restaurant_district: ", restaurant_district)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because your selectors are too specific, and you don't check if the tag was found or not. One solution is loosen the selectors (the `lemon--div-XXX...` selectors will probably change in the near future anyway):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import csv
import re

my_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
bs = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

yelp_containers = bs.select('li:contains("All Results") ~ li:contains("read more")')

for idx, item in enumerate(yelp_containers, 1):
    print("--- Restaurant number #", idx)

    restaurant_title = item.h3.get_text(strip=True)
    restaurant_title = re.sub(r'^[\d.\s]+', '', restaurant_title)
    restaurant_address = item.select_one('[class*="secondaryAttributes"]').get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')[1]
    restaurant_numReview = item.select_one('[class*="reviewCount"]').get_text(strip=True)
    restaurant_numReview = re.sub(r'[^\d.]', '', restaurant_numReview)
    restaurant_starCount = item.select_one('[class*="stars"][aria-label]')['aria-label']
    restaurant_starCount = re.sub(r'[^\d.]', '', restaurant_starCount)
    pr = item.select_one('[class*="priceRange"]')
    restaurant_price = pr.get_text(strip=True) if pr else '-'
    restaurant_category = [a.get_text(strip=True) for a in item.select('[class*="priceRange"] ~ span a')]
    restaurant_district = item.select_one('[class*="secondaryAttributes"]').get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')[-1]

    print(restaurant_title)
    print(restaurant_address)
    print(restaurant_numReview)
    print(restaurant_price)
    print(restaurant_category)
    print(restaurant_district)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
--- Restaurant number # 1
Fog Harbor Fish House
Pier 39
5487
$$
['Seafood', 'Bars']
Fisherman's Wharf
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Restaurant number # 2
The House
1230 Grant Ave
4637
$$$
['Asian Fusion']
North Beach/Telegraph Hill
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```